# searching cross-fields DIH indexed data on Solr

Tags: solr, dih

I got indexed some data of a MySQL db in my Solr engine. It works fine when I search keywords along with the field names : "q=texted_value:car" returns my db record

```
<doc><str name="id">6</str><str name="texted_value">car</str></doc>
```

However, I need to be able to perform full-text search in my db, without giving the fieldname (q=car). So how do we do that ? If it's including Transformer or Processor in my data-config will you please guide me ?

my data-config.xml :

```
<entity name="test0" 
pk="id"
query="select * from test0">
<field column="value_t" name="texted_value" />
</entity>
```

Thx

Comment: Uh, what kind of (fields and) queries do you have in mind? Please give us a few examples. Are you saying that you need to search multiple fields in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common technique used to search across fields in Solr is to use `copyField` directive. This copies values from the original field to destination field. Normally it is indexed without norms & not stored.

```xml
<copyField source="columnA" dest="textAll" maxChars="20" />
<copyField source="columnB" dest="textAll" maxChars="20" />
<copyField source="columnC" dest="textAll" maxChars="20" />
....
```

Make `textAll` field as default field in your `schema.xml`,

```xml
<defaultSearchField>textAll</defaultSearchField>
```

Now you can search  **http://server/solr/select/?q=car** this will search across all your fields. This will increase the performance of your searching, instead of searching each fields individually you search for one field `textAll`. It comes with a price of increase in indexing time & file size.

Read [Solr copyFields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the searchable columns with the [DisMax Query Parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin).  `copyField` will also work but requires schema changes.  Both are good options depending on the situation.

**?q=car&qf=column1 column2&defType=dismax

> ```
>     //search for the word "car"
>     ?q=car
>
>     //specify all the columns to search in
>     &qf=column1 column2
>
>     //use dismax
>     &defType=dismax
> ```